# Is there any way to block obnoxious CSS popups and overlays?

Tags: css, adblock

These days, I have a hard time browsing any site without being forced to dismiss some stupid delayed CSS popup or overlay asking me to sign up to some newsletter or something else. (see https://www.javacodegeeks.com/ and http://www.journaldev.com/ for examples)

It's one thing to popup a small frame in the bottom corner, but another alltogether to create a modal window that must be dealt with before continuing to read.

Is there any way to block these?

Comment: User agent switcher, appear as a search bot

Answer (score 0):

I use a Chrome extension called [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha)

It allows you to add CSS to any website so you can override existing CSS to hide popups/overlays

Answer (score -1):

At [adblockplus.org/subscriptions](https://adblockplus.org/subscriptions#type_other) you can - in addition to the regular ad blocking filter lists - also find non-ad blocking lists such as *Fanboy's Annoyances* which is supposed to get rid of various annoyances around the web.